# Can't get function to work after adding value to array

Tags: jquery

Hello and thanks for reading this.

I have this little query validation I made and I'm fairly new to jquery so I'm kinda happy about how far I managed to get so far.

```
var btnResultv2 = $('#btnResultv2');
    btnResultv2.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    var FieldArrayv2 = [
        'txtnamev2',
        'txtpassv2',
        'txtpass2v2'
    ];

    FieldArrayv2.forEach(function (id) {
        $('#' + id).bind('input propertychange', function () {
            ValidateFieldsV2(FieldArrayv2, btnResultv2);
        });
    });
function ValidateFieldsV2(paths, button) {
var checker = false

$.each(paths, function (index, value) {
    //alert($('#' + value).val().length);
    var label = $("label[for='" + $('#' + value).attr('id') + "']");
    if ($('#' + value).val().length < 1) {
        label.text("* Required");
        label.show();
        checker = true
    }
    else {
        label.hide();
    }
});

if (checker != true) {
    button.removeAttr("disabled");
} else {
    button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
};
```

Now I would like to change the array like below so I can add a lenght parameter to my validation.

```
FieldArrayv3[name] = [
        { name: 'txtnamev3', length: 3 },
        { name: 'txtpassv3', length: 4 }
    ];
```

Not sure if this is 100% correct way to change the array, but my question is how can I make the code below to work with the new array ( or another one that does the same)

```
FieldArrayv2.forEach(function (id) {
    $('#' + id).bind('input propertychange', function () {
        ValidateFieldsV2(FieldArrayv2, btnResultv2);
    });
});
```

Thanks for your time and all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the array of strings to be an array of objects, your argument in the foreach is now the object not the string id, so you need to modify the jQuery selector like so:

```
FieldArrayv2.forEach(function (obj) {
    $('#' + obj.name).bind('input propertychange', function () {
        ValidateFieldsV2(FieldArrayv2, btnResultv2);
    });
});
```

The `ValidateFieldsV2` function will also need to be modified, because `value` is now an object not a string. For example on this line:

```
var label = $("label[for='" + $('#' + value).attr('id') + "']");
//                                    ^^ should be value.name
if ($('#' + value).val().length < 1) {
//          ^^ should be value.name
```

This assumes your array looks like:

```
FieldArrayv2 = [
    { name: 'txtnamev3', length: 3 },
    { name: 'txtpassv3', length: 4 }
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but after changing my code to your ide, it never hits this part. : ValidateFieldsV2(FieldArrayv2, btnResultv2);

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
FieldArrayv3[name] = [
    { name: 'txtnamev3', length: 3 },
    { name: 'txtpassv3', length: 4 }
];
```

... is not how you build an object array. You are after something like...

```
var FieldArrayv3 = [
    { name: 'txtnamev3', length: 3 },
    { name: 'txtpassv3', length: 4 }
];
```

You don't set the 'key' in the declaration. But with an object array there are no 'keys'. You will need to query it like so...

```
FieldArrayv3.forEach(function (field) {
    $('#' + field.name).on('input propertychange', function () {
        ValidateFieldsV2(FieldArrayv2, btnResultv2);
    });
});
```

I also changed your `bind` method to `on` as `bind` is now deprecated.

Comment: Tried your example and i get this message in the konsole log.
ReferenceError: FieldArrayv3 is not defined

Comment: Yer I took the second and third block of code and added/changed it to mine, and then it gave that error

Comment: I think half the issue here is that you have all of these `v2`/`v3` you should simplify your code and remove these and just have one version of your code in one file. that will clear up a lot of things for you.